# Is it possible to get Date tag from non natural sentence?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to get DATE information from a sentence.
It is combined with only codes such as ***"ST JOHN 100H -OPEN TEXAS APR 05/08"***
What I need from the sentence is ***APR 05/08*** which is dates.

I ran my code but got no luck..

```
        doc = nlp('ST JOHN 100H -OPEN TEXAS APR 05/08')
        for token in doc:
            print(token.text, token.idx, token.pos_, token.ent_type_)
```

but got these..

```
ST 0 PROPN 
JOHN 3 PROPN PERSON
100H 8 PROPN PERSON
-OPEN 13 PUNCT PERSON
TEXAS 19 PROPN 
APR 25 PROPN ORG
05/08 29 NUM
```

Is it possible to extract NERs from non nature setence??
Sombody help
Thanks, in advance

Comment: spaCy's NER gets really hung up on capitalization, since that is usually reserved for proper nouns and starts of sentences. Unless you specifically trained your ner to only pick up on things like `APR 25`, it will fail to pick those up properly out of the box

Comment: I should've look for how to train..thanks. I will be back.